# GSON - How to always include millisecond in json?

Tags: java, c#, json, sql-server

I'm building Android application which interacts with REST API built on .NET.

If my table in SQL Server has 2 rows with the following datetime values:

- 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000
- 2019-01-01 00:00:00.113

Then the returned json will have the following values:

- 2019-01-01T00:00:00
- 2019-01-01T00:00:00.113

So I don't know how to provide the pattern for setDateFormat when creating an instance of Gson.

If I use `GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")`, then my gson can generalize on both cases but it loses millisecond part.

If I use `GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")`, then my gson won't lose millisecond part in the second case but it will throw an exception when dealing with the first case.

How can I successfully parse time in two cases but still achieve millisecond? Any provided solution would be appreciated. I don't mind if things I have to is server side or client side.

Comment: Just make sure in your JSON text/data you always have the milliseconds part even if it is equal to 0. Then whichever module is parsing the JSON can use a uniform pattern. I mean this assumption sounds incorrect "Then the returned json will have the following values (meaning 2 possible formats)". You can probably make it 1 single format always in your JSON.

Comment: @peter.petrov Because I configure my API to return json, rather than xml in my WebApiConfig.cs file. So I feel I can't control how my API builds its content. How can I create my own json format?

Comment: @peter.petrov thank you. By your hint, I can finally tell my API to always include millisecond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a workaround, I found solution myself, thanks to peter.petrov

It is because I configure my API to return data in json format, rather than xml, in my WebApiConfig.cs. So I feel I can't control how it builds its time format. But I finally found it. This is my WebApiConfig.cs file:

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
json.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff";
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Now I server always includes millisecond, no matter what.

That's it.